# How can i convert a dynamic web page to PDF using html2canvas and JSPDF

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, html2canvas, jspdf

i have a nicely presented styled tables and charts on my web page designed as a report to an analysis evaluation. I looked up a lot of code snippets to convert html pages to pdf. However they all seem difficult and code insensitive to generate my kind of report. So i then encounter *html2canvas* to convert my page to an image and use jspdf to convert to pdf. with my code below i can't seem to be able to get it right.

```
    <script type='text/javascript' src='../js/jquery-2.1.1.js' > </script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="../js/jsPDF-master/jspdf.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="../js/jsPDF-master/jspdf.plugin.standard_fonts_metrics.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="../js/jsPDF-master/jspdf.plugin.split_text_to_size.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="../js/jsPDF-master/jspdf.plugin.from_html.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="../js/jsPDF-master/jspdf.plugin.addhtml.js"></script>     
    <script type='text/javascript' src="../js/html2canvas-master/dist/html2canvas.js"></script>

<script language = 'JavaScript' type = 'text/javascript' >
        $(document).ready(function () {               
            var d_canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
            var context = d_canvas.getContext('2d');
            context.moveTo(20, 20);
            context.lineTo(100, 20);
            context.fillStyle = "#999";
            context.beginPath();
            context.arc(100, 100, 75, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
            context.fill();
            context.fillStyle = "orange";
            context.fillRect(20, 20, 50, 50);
            context.font = "24px Helvetica";
            context.fillStyle = "#000";
            context.fillText("Canvas", 50, 130);


            $('#download').click(function () {
                alert();
                html2canvas($("#canvas"), {
                    onrendered: function (canvas) {
                        var imgData = canvas.toDataURL(
                                'image/png');
                        var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm');
                        doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 10, 10);
                        doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
                    }
                });
            });
        });

        function demoPDF() {
            var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');

            var source = $('#loadPDFDiv')[0];
            doc.fromHTML(source, 15, 15, {'width': 180});
            doc.output("dataurlnewwindow");
        }
    </script> 


<div id="loadPDFDiv">
        <h4 style="padding-bottom: 5px; padding-left: 10px; display: inherit;">List of Alternatives</h4>
        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" id="thetable" class="tablesorter">
            <thead>
                <tr>
            <div class="rowBottowBorder">
                <th width="35%" align="left" scope="col"><div style='margin-right: 10px;'><span class="style1">Alternative Name</span></div></th>
                <th width="40%" align="left" scope="col"><div style='margin-right: 10px;'><span class="style1">Alternative Group</span></div></th>
                </tr></thead>
                <tbody id="refreshTable">
                    <?php
                    try {
                        $wsdl_url = 'http://localhost:8080/Mamca/MamcaWS?WSDL';
                        $client = new SOAPClient($wsdl_url, array(
                            "features" => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS
                        ));
                        $params = array(
                            'projectid' => $_SESSION['projectID'],
                        );
                        $return = $client->getAlternativeListByProjectID($params);
                        if (isset($return->return)) {
                            foreach ($return->return as $eachItem) {
                                echo "<tr align='center'>";
                                echo "<td align='left' class='rowDisplay'> <a href = '#' class = 'rowNumber2'>" . $eachItem->alternativedescription . "</a></td>";
                                echo "<td align='left' class='rowDisplay'>" . $eachItem->alternativeGroup . "</td>";
                                echo "</tr>";
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (Exception $e) {
                        echo "Exception occured: " . $e;
                    }
                    ?>                                       
                </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="canboy"/>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="480" height="320"></canvas> 
    <button id="download">Download Pdf</button>
    <button  onclick="demoPDF();">Download</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Have you tried to use jpg instead of png?

Comment: You realise that by going the image to PDF route you're losing perhaps the biggest advantage of PDF? That you can zoom without loss of quality and that text remains crisp and legible (not to mention selectable and if needed can be accessible)?

Comment: @DavidvanDriessche the issue is that i chart some charts from other plugins to display on this report. to me loss of quality is the least of my troubles.

Comment: @kiks73 both works now. i realized that the included js scripts are incompatible so i used a min version.